# how to display caret via rails link_to for dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the little drop down menu symbol in my rails app that uses twitter bootstrap via the link_to method in my rails app.

I can't figure out how to do it.  When I add the `<b class="caret"></b>` (that twitter bootstrap uses) to the `'Setup '` argument below, it gets escaped and shows up as text not html.

`<%= link_to 'Setup ', root_path, :id => 'setupdrop', :'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', :class => 'dropdown-toggle' %>`

Of all the rails examples that I have seen so far, none use link_to when using this feature of TBS (and include the caret).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,
`<%= link_to 'Setup <b class="caret"></b>'.html_safe, root_path, :id => 'setupdrop', :'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', :class => 'dropdown-toggle' %>`

Comment: Nice!  I think I'll go convert my html into erb. :)

Answer (score 1):

I remember having an issue with this very thing.  If I remember correctly it had to do with the tag order - it had to be inside a `<li>` tag.  Here's my code that works:

```
<ul class="nav" role="navigation">
  <li class="explore">
    <%= link_to 'explore <b class="caret"></b>'.html_safe, root_path, :id => 'setupdrop', :'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', :class => 'dropdown-toggle' %>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
      <li class="nav-header">Majors</li>
      <li class="dropdown-link"><%= link_to "View All", majors_path %>
      <li class="dropdown-link"><a href="#">By School</a></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-link"><a href="#">Recently Added</a></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-link"><a href="#">Most Liked</a></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks to Amar I didn't have to play around with converting it into erb as he did it.  Here's what my code now looks like with Amar's help.

Comment: Oops, I think your `aria-labelledby` should refer to your id in your `link_to`.  But thanks for the help, you and Amar had it right, all I needed was the `.html_safe`.

Comment: Yep, I missed that aria-labelledby.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1):

link_to takes a block so you can do

```
link_to root_path, :id => 'setupdrop', :'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', :class => 'dropdown-toggle' do
  Setup 
  <b class="caret"></b>
end
```